# How to scan Date in java for jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

I am using jdbc. there is a Date type in my table. I want to insert data to table using PreparedStatement and i want to take values from user in date format using ----

`Product product = new Product()`;

`Date date = product.setDate(scan.(?))`?

How to scan **java.sql.Date** type from **Scanner**? Or any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Read the `date` as `string` and convert it into correct format using `SimpleDateFormat` (if needed) and do

```
java.sql.Date.valueOf(String date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dates can be formatted in many ways.  For example all of the following are commonly used formats for the first of May, 2015:

- May 1, 2015
- 5/1/2015
- 1/5/2015
- 2015-05-01

Note that the middle two are both easily interpreted as Jan 1 if the wrong assumptions are taken.  For this reason, there's no way to parse dates reliably without knowing the format of the date beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading Date from Console then use Scanner and later convert it to java.sql.Date by using SimpleDateFormat, you need to specify the correct format though.